# Error with java.util.Scanner

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It runs for me.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: but in my case, when i click run nothing happens

Comment: When you click "run" something happens. You just don't have any user prompts so it looks like it's not running. I put your code in my IDE and it works.

Comment: thanks to everyone :)

Comment: Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: In eclipse, when click run as java application nothing happens @ EJoshuaS

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs, but you should add some user prompts:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TimeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input integer:");
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input string:");
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input double:");
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

It should be noted that you will have an issue trying to get your string input. You'll want to clear your input by adding another `String s = scan.nextLine();` after your `String s = scan.nextInt();`